# Browser addon, for auto-filling common form fields in job applications?

Tags: web-browser, forms

I have an extension, Lastpass, which gets me part of the way there. Lastpass can remember your name, address, phone number etc and fill them in automatically.

However, it doesn't recognise fields such as 'qualifications', 'employment history' and 'reference details'.

Is there a browser extension which does? I don't care what browser. I'd pay up to, say, 5USD for it.